# Error in importing model in django

Tags: python, django

Error in importing model in another file. Basically I want to use

```
>>> from mysite.blog.models import Blog
>>> b = Blog(name='Beatles Blog', tagline='All the latest Beatles news.')
>>> b.save()
```

but in a python file[ scrap.py ] to add values to models but error is on import of models in this file . any help ??

```
from models import QuestionBox  // Error in this line
```

Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrap.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models import QuestionBox
  File "/home/sourabh/Django/QASite/QAsite/QAapp/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/home/sourabh/Django/QASite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if settings.DATABASES and DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/home/sourabh/Django/QASite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/sourabh/Django/QASite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Dir Tree

```
    .
    |-- manage.py
    |-- QAapp
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- __init__.pyc
    |   |-- migrations
    |   |   |-- 0001_initial.py
    |   |   |-- 0001_initial.pyc
    |   |   |-- 0002_initial.py
    |   |   |-- 0002_initial.pyc
    |   |   |-- 0003_initial.py
    |   |   |-- 0003_initial.pyc
    |   |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |   `-- __init__.pyc
    |   |-- models.py
    |   |-- models.pyc
    |   |-- scrap.py
    |   |-- tests.py
    |   `-- views.py
    |-- QAappdb
    `-- QAsite
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- __init__.pyc
        |-- settings.py
        |-- settings.pyc
        |-- urls.py
        `-- wsgi.py
```

model file:

```
class QuestionBox :

    topic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sub_topic = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    question = models.TextField()
    options = models.TextField()
    correct_option = models.TextField()

    total_attempt = models.IntegerField()
    correct_attempt = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: What is your DATABASES setting in settings.py file? The traceback tells that the settings aren't properly configured.

Comment: can you show your settings.py ? You should have a settings called `DATABASES  = `

Comment: do you use virtualenv? How do you run server/shell?

Comment: sry lappy just went off. yes i am using virtualenv and south. i did update DATABASES = . but some admin removed it i think ??

Comment: DATABASE : http://ideone.com/ggl5Su

Comment: got it : it was just a silly mistake . didn't inherit model class from model.Models . see in code above. thanx anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue :

1) Python manage.py include the path settings file to be used for database.
2) I was importing a model [QuestionBox ] which was trying to import DATABASE settings 
   that was causing error.

Patch:

1) Explicitly include these lines on top of file [scrap.py ] which you wanna run directly .

```
import os
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "QAsite.settings")
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to check:

1. Based upon you file path you would need the app name before the module you are importing. so:

   from QAapp.models import QuestionBox
2. Check the file path / directory path of your `settings.py` file.
3. Your models class should read:

   class Questionbox(models.Model):
   ...

Hopefully this helps fix the issue.